# Dojo RSA configuration and usage

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, dojo, rsa

I am new to Dojo and I want to be able to use the RSA module to encrypt some information using a public key that is received from a website.

Is there any information or examples on how to do this?

I have found the library dojox.encoding.crypto.RSAKey but there is no information:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/encoding/crypto/RSAKey.html

I found Dojo because I was researching: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

Now I want to learn Dojo but my primary reason to use it is the RSA library.

Ps.: I don't want to be lectured on the dangers of RSA on the client side, neither why I shouldn't be doing RSA on JavaScript side.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: replaced example values with provided ones. 
I'm not familiar with RSA, but general use of dojo's RSAKey module would be as follow (according to its [source code](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/encoding/crypto/RSAKey.js)):

```js
require([
 "dojo/dom",
 "dojox/encoding/crypto/RSAKey"
],function(dom, RSAKeyModule){
  
  var RSAKey = new RSAKeyModule();
  
  var n= "8efebfa74157b9447e1bc729d5e2a459ee888e87dc7ed764b473e513edba‌​7696a957871ff7a4941e‌​d360d1b42a9788bdc52a‌​8b659357dc8f252e6cc5‌​f5bbf5c659cc9e9837df‌​4ca6eee1c47889b055ac‌​3802bb9491e88483491b‌​08dff9e9472d99341134‌​bcfc4ecf38915553bda0‌​8f943089377a95c7118f‌​ebcef2841288aedb1b8b‌​a22e211da2ab527d26d7‌​accf2e05421260a23f06‌​cf2b13e0ffd51e8f401b‌​c113768027ad29c37156‌​4d179c82639061272e4f‌​940bf50ba6490933f788‌​715f8c268dd2c85a461e‌​899ba416a51557fec7a9‌​a4f1ed3df95cf5bd14bb‌​529dd331b9a79828366a‌​9589deb32e730369cd62‌​352ef7fdd9297e1193f4‌​a33e01289a6f"
  
  var e = "10001";
  
  RSAKey.setPublic(n, e);
  var encrypted = RSAKey.encrypt("abc");
  dom.byId("result").innerHTML = encrypted;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

See [dojo/request/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/xhr.html) module - could be helpful for receiving key.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: This is my RSA Public Key:
modulus: 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
public exponent: 10001

Comment: in my java application it can encrypt a message just fine and decrypt using the private key correctly:

Comment: Encrypting 'abc': T1uAc60TKQV163iQSEdBvRpkWCBn0p1an8HdeBznaiToElYImWttgd3R4epseVoC3+DZMB/wySgdlpfhoml4FET7ouSRXNGLKugqK3rZZ5NghWMo08/yJURBBagORUeBmybIHyete1gnctf3Zh8TEFF0Qlt6Kcxd61/eBIgroSbJDdDW6rQklC7bkrTqVMlfftv1t/KY2r8rtOQ11bLMaBnhpKj6UC2hJD5hrbTgnMLkWOPTC097pu4+m8sGjsrjttmcO9u+gnUGhfpHUwvkTct9L7rCrgrvvkPVpnmdI2Be8sj6G5O7WjChnOcedVttI8Yt6URtieIDk4Mxrsa8Uw==

Decrypting 'abc': abc

Comment: But when I encrypt using Dojo RSA the encrypted message cannot be decrypted with the following error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block

Comment: I am sure I am doing something wrong with Dojo, thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my code with public key you have provided and it encrypt something. (I can't tell whether it is expected output or not.) I got similar error in snippet when my `n` was too small - make sure this variable contains whole string after retrieving it. Note: After pasting modulus into editor it shows some red dots. I guess they are whitespaces - should they be there?